# Kali Linux - Can't move or resize my terminal

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following problem.

I logged into my linux account, opened the terminal and tried to resize it and it didn't even show the resize icon. After not being able to resize my terminal I tried to move it which also didn't work. I use virtual box if it helps.

Is there a possibility, to reset the settings in a way that it would let me resize and move it again?

Picture. on the right, my regular terminal (that has a problem), on the left the root terminal that works fine
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem your'e facing. But I got my problem solved. So you can also give it a try what I did. So to fix that you can go to the "view" option at the very top of your terminal >> then you may find your "Hide Window Borders" selected, which is responsible for your problem. So just simply put off the tick mark to deselect it. >> then you may get rid of the problem. Thank you.